# For a B2B Enterprise REST API, should requesting an access token in oAuth2 invalidate previously granted access tokens to that Client ID?

Tags: oauth-2.0

For a B2B REST API servicing Enterprise clients who may have multiple applications using a Client ID/Secret:

If you send a request for an oAuth2 access token for a specific Client ID and Client Secret and receive an access token then later on send another request for a token with that same Client ID/Secret, should that invalidate the previous access token?

In other words, in this case, should a Client ID/Secret be able to request and use multiple valid access tokens?  Are there different cases where this should be implemented or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OAuth2 is generally about a user delegating access to a client, so in the case where a client has many users (as it usually will), it will most definitely be using multiple access tokens since they will apply to different users.

Consider the situation where you grant access to your Google account to another online application (the client). Google issues an access token which might allow the client to read your contacts, for example, using Google's OAuth2 APIs (with your prior approval). Obviously it can only access *your* contacts with this token, not other people's. Google may issue many different access tokens to the same client, but each may correspond to a different user and/or resource.

The same authorization server may issue tokens for many different resources, so even in the case where there is no interaction with a user (as in the "client credentials" grant), a client may still need to manage multiple tokens.

Whether the authorization server invalidates a token when another is requested for the same user, audience, scope etc., would be implementation dependent. A client wouldn't usually need to do this and would normally use a refresh token to obtain a new token when its existing one was about to expire. I'd say it's generally more important that a user can invalidate existing tokens they have authorized, and that tokens can be invalidated for a particular client. Of course, this also requires that the resource server has some way of checking for token revocation before granting access.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a client can have several access tokens. It's meaningful, we're actually using.

Consider that tokens may have different scopes, so a client may have a token with scope "res1" for a resource and a another token with scope "res2" for a different resource.

Another use case may be to request a refresh token with several scopes, e.g. "read write" and use it to get a "read" scoped access token to initialize a management GUI, then get a new access token for each write transaction.

You can argue whether it's good design/implementation or not but it's definitely technically possible and not forbidden by the standard.